# Can't compare getPriority() value in firebase DB security rules using `>=` operator

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm using priority on the object to check permissions of the user. However I'm experiencing strange behavior - when I try to compare priority with greater then or equal operator (>=) in DB security rules (realtime DB), I get permission denied error. However, when I use equal operator (===), then it works fine. I need to use >= operator, as I'm checking minimal permissions value for given action.

Here is concrete example:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "tiles": {
      "$boardId": {
        ".read": "root.child('boards/'+$boardId+'/owner').val() === auth.uid || root.child('boards/'+$boardId+'/visibility').val() === 'public' || root.child('boardsPermissions/' + $boardId + '/' + auth.uid).getPriority() >= 10",
        ".write": "root.child('boards/'+$boardId+'/owner').val() === auth.uid || root.child('boardsPermissions/' + $boardId + '/' + auth.uid).getPriority() >= 20"

      }
    }
  }
}
```

If try to write to location `tiles/board-1/tile-1` with user `user-1` with this DB record in permissions node:

```
'permissions/board-1/user-1': {
    .priority: 20
 }
```

I got an error, however if I change the write rule to form below, I can write to given node.

```
".write": "root.child('permissions/' + $boardId + '/' + auth.uid).getPriority() === 20"
```

I know that first condition is false (user is not owner of the tile). I believe this may be a bug, but I want to confirm it first. Can please someone have a look?

What is also strange is, that it start working once and I made successful write to DB, but then it stop working again. Is there some delay between publishing security rules and them taking effect in DB?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Also asked [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2939). Please note when you cross-post!

Comment: I suspect this happens when your priority is a string (e.g. you set it from an input field without converting to a number). In RTDB rules, `===` is confusingly converted to `==`, so `"100" === 100` will work, but `>=` requires a number, so `"100" >= 40` probably does not.